# Is it valid to have a constructor call another constructor of the same class in its initialization list?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Data
{
    private:
    int day, month, year;
    public:
    Data() : Data(0,0,0) {};
    Data(int d, int m, int y) : day(d) , month(m), year(y) {}
    void print() { std::cout << day << " " << month << " "<< year << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Data a;
    a.print(); //ok - output: 0,0,0 and no compiler errors
}
```

A constructor does not have a returning value, and a constructor is called when an object is created, meaning the data can be initialized, so when I call a constructor from another constructor, is this completely valid?

I've also noticed that `Data() { Data(0,0,0); };` does **NOT** initialize the current class data members.

Why is it that `Data() : Data(0,0,0) {};` works and `Data() { Data(0,0,0); };` does not?

Comment: Check out [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor). Your second example just creates an unnamed temp on the stack and destroys it. Its got nothing to do with construction.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfect practice to do perform:

```
Data() : Data(0,0,0) {};
```

You are simply calling utilizing your initializer list.

The reason

```
Data() {
    Data(0,0,0);
}
```

does no work is because all you have done is created an "anonymous" `Data` object on the stack within the Constructor which will be destructed as soon as the default constructor is completed.